# Recreate Tufte Moiré vibration

Tags: r, plot

Tufte gives a good bad example of why cross hatching is distorting, the shimmer effect (The Visual Display of Quantitative Information, 2001, p. 108) that looks similar to:

[image]

Though his is crisper.  How could I replicate this in R?  As it's not considered good practice figuring out the easiest way to replicate is proving challenging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an option using `abline`:

```
plot(NA,NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100))
for(i in seq(-15,600,6)) {
  abline(i, -3, lwd=6)
}
```

[image]

**Edit** per Tyler: Here's what I used exactly in a knitr doc, just as annoying as the original.

```
plot(NA,NA, xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,100), ylab=NA, xlab=NA, yaxt='n', xaxt='n', bty = "n")
for(i in seq(-15,500,6)) {
  abline(i, -3, lwd=4)
}
```

Comment: This was the best of the bad answers.  Not often you want bad answers :-)  This was the trueist to Tufte's  +1

Comment: Thanks Tyler. Sometimes it feels good to be bad. But please don't tell Hadley. I don't want to get kicked out of the club.

Answer (score 9):

`polygon` to the rescue:

```
plot(0:1,type="n")
polygon(
  x=c(1,1,2,2),
  y=c(1,0,0,1),
  density=10,
  angle=135,
  lwd=5, 
  border=NA
)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice response and clever use of polygon.  The ends were a little rounded which is fine but I was trying to get as close to Tufte's as possible.  +1  Thank you.

Comment: @TylerRinker - easily fixed by adding a `lend=` argument. `?par` lists all of the myriad options you can use to adjust a line type. Also, you could just make the polygon larger than the plot area if you want it clipped. Or use `?clip` before plotting the polygon - e.g:. `clip(1.1,1.9,0.1,0.9)`

Comment: Nice good call.  I rarely work in base graphics any more and have forget a ton of what you can do.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, here's a `ggplot2` solution, as always the challenge is getting the underlying data right...

```
hatch <- function(xsequence, ysequence, weight = 1) {
  require(ggplot2) 
  df <- data.frame(x = c(rep(0, length(ysequence)),xsequence, xsequence, rep(max(xsequence), length(ysequence))),
                   y = c(ysequence, rep(max(ysequence), length(xsequence)), rep(0, length(xsequence)), ysequence), 
                   group = seq_along(1:(length(xsequence) + length(ysequence))))
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(group = group), size = weight)
  print(p + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                  axis.title = element_blank()))

}
hatch(1:100, 1:40, 1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the grid approach.  This one required more engineering.  +1